# Subscription to Observable.ToList() not firing

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, system.reactive

I have created an observable from an enumerable.

```
var enumerable = CreateMyVeryOwnEnumerable();
var obs = enumerable.ToObservable();
var observableOfList = obs.ToList();

observableOfList.Subscribe(o => Console.Write(o));
```

The problem I have is that the Console.Write is never hit.

What could be the problem? Could it be that the enumerable never ends?

Comment: what does the 'CreateMyVeryOwnEnumerable()' method provide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### In your code:

If 'CreateMyVeryOwnEnumerable' creates a non-terminating IEnumerable, then any call that requires all of the results values completely will block forever - this would happen if you called ToList(), Min(), Max(), Reverse() etc on the IEnumerable.

If 'CreateMyVeryOwnEnumerable' gives a terminating IEnumerable, then the Console.Write call is hit with a List instance;

#### Fix

If your goal is to just consume (print) each value of the enumerable using Subscribe, then you can just use:

```
   static void Main()
    {
        var enumerable = CreateMyVeryOwnEnumerable();
        var obs = enumerable.ToObservable();

        obs.Subscribe(o => Console.WriteLine(o));
        
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static IEnumerable<int> CreateMyVeryOwnEnumerable()
    {
        // non-terminating
        while (true)
            yield return 0;

        // terminating
        //return Enumerable.Range(0, 100);
    }
```

Note however that the Subscribe call is now blocking if the original enumerable was non-terminating.  No amount of key mashing will close the console window.

If your goal is to actually consume the List in the subscribe method, you have no choice but to make it terminating.

Comment: That was the problem! The sequence didn't end! now it works. Thank you!